# how to create schema in mysql and how to import existing record into the database?

Tags: mysql, sql, centos

I have file with name data that contain information like in my linux machine

```
  2 Mar 1 1234 141.98.80.59
  1 Mar 1 1234 171.239.249.233
  5 Mar 1 admin 116.110.119.156
  4 Mar 1 admin1 177.154.8.15
  2 Mar 1 admin 141.98.80.63
```

I have created a database in Mysql with name "invaliduser" and inside that i have create table "invalidlog" and i created a schema like this

```
CREATE TABLE invalidlog(
    Count INT,
    Month CHAR(10),
    Date INT(10),
    User VARCHAR(50),
    IP_ADD INT UNSIGNED
);
```

when i am trying to import the data file in mysql with the following command

```
mysql -u root -p invaliduser < data
```

it is showing me error:

> ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax;
> check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the
> right syntax to use near '2 Mar 1 1234 141.98.80.59
> 1 Mar 1 1234 171.239.249.233
> 5 Mar 1 admin' at line 1

This is a correct way to create schema?

Comment: Does `141.98.80.63` look like an INTEGER to you?

Comment: If you want to use this `mysql -u root -p invaliduser < data` then the `data` file has to be a EXPORT from a MySQL database table and not just some random space delimited stuff

Comment: I suggest you look at this [LOAD DATA](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html) and see if you can crowbar the data into the table that way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot simply import the data into your table, you will need to generate valid SQL syntax from the file. This can be done with awk:

```
awk -v sinq="'" '{ print "INSERT INTO invalidlog (Count,Month,Date,User,IPADD) VALUES ("sinq$1sinq","sinq$2sinq","sinq$3sinq","sinq$4sinq","sinq$5sinq");"}' file
```

Set up a variable sinq to be a single quote and then use this along with the space separated fields to generate the required sql.

Output:

```
INSERT INTO invalidlog (Count,Month,Date,User,IPADD) VALUES ('2','Mar','1','1234','141.98.80.59');
INSERT INTO invalidlog (Count,Month,Date,User,IPADD) VALUES ('1','Mar','1','1234','171.239.249.233');
INSERT INTO invalidlog (Count,Month,Date,User,IPADD) VALUES ('5','Mar','1','admin','116.110.119.156');
INSERT INTO invalidlog (Count,Month,Date,User,IPADD) VALUES ('4','Mar','1','admin1','177.154.8.15');
INSERT INTO invalidlog (Count,Month,Date,User,IPADD) VALUES ('2','Mar','1','admin','141.98.80.6');
```

The awk command can then be integrated with mysql:

```
mysql -u root -p pass invaliduser <<< "$(awk -v sinq="'" '{ print "INSERT INTO invalidlog (Count,Month,Date,User,IPADD) VALUES ("sinq$1sinq","sinq$2sinq","sinq$3sinq","sinq$4sinq","sinq$5sinq");"}' file)"
```